# How to make a loop to plot several graphs using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my dataframe:

```
x1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
x2 <- c(3,4,5,6)
x3 <- c(5,6,7,8)
x4 <- c(7,8,9,10)
x5 <- c(8,7,6,5)
df <- c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)
```

I choose 3 variables from my dataframe to plot 3 separate scatterplots each against x1 and store these in a character vector:

```
varlist <- c("x2","x4","x5")
```

So I want to create a function to make 3 independent scatterplots of x1 with x2, x1 with x4 and x1 with x5, using `ggplot`, where `xx` and `yy` will be the different pairs of variables to plot:

```
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(mapping = aes(x = xx, y = yy)) +
  geom_smooth(mapping = aes(x = xx, y = yy))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
mapply(function(y) print(ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_point(aes_string(x = "x1", y = y)) +
  geom_smooth(aes_string(x = "x1", y = y))), y=c("x2","x4","x5"))
```

Note : I used  `df <- data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)` instead of `df <- c(x1,x2,x3,x4,x5)`

`x` is set to `x1`, `mapply` will loop over `y` which contains the different variables we want to have plotted against `x1`.

Comment: You may also check the `map` from `purrr` tidyverse package.